# android set bottom line and cursor color of an edit text

Tags: android

i have an edit text view in my android app.
this is des Design of this view:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/DefaultGreen"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColorHint="@color/DefaultGreen"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

Text ist green.
i would like to make the bottom line transparent/invisible and the cursor color black. at the moment both are white.

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **For bottom line transparent/invisible**

   android:background="@null"
2. **For cursor color**

> define colorAccent inside your styles.xml

```
<!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

**Edit:**
Setting the android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null should result in the use of android:textColor as the cursor color.

Attribute "textCursorDrawable" is available in API level 12 and higher

**Setting Background Bottom line null**

create drawable file inside your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#00000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

and set this as background to your edittext.

Comment: colorAccent works fine- but this change the color of my selected tabs to. is there another way? background="@null" doesn't work. bottom line is not hidden